# QtSensors / QML Device Rotation readings are not unique?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to read the pitch of the device. For my ideal use, the direction I am trying to read is the direction of the rear camera.  Qt Sensors and the Rotation element is how I am to do this (There is the Tilt Sensor, but thats the same)

I've compiled a table of lifting the top edge from almost flat, face up flipping over until face down (rotation, device orientation):

```
rot|ori| visual pitch
13 | 5 | _
32 | 5 | _
50 | 1 | \
69 | 1 | \
78 | 1 | \ <-+
90 | 1 | |   +-problem 
74 | 1 | / <-+
62 | 1 | /
47 | 1 | /
29 | 6 | _
19 | 6 | _
12 | 6 | _
 8 | 6 | _
```

Even though the flip motion never changed direction, the values go 78, 90, 74. Since the device orientation never changed, I can't tell the difference. What is the proper way to get the rotation past 90? I'm expecting values like 135, 140, etc. (iOS, Android)

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtSensors 5.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    RotationSensor {
        id: rotationSensor
        active: true
    }
    OrientationSensor {
        id: orientation
        active: true
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log("rotation.x, orientation:", rotationSensor.reading.x, orientation.reading.orientation)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: provide a [mcve].

Comment: Added a minimal example. Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to take in to account the rotation around other axes. unless I need z rotation, I prefer to use TiltSensor (only x and y-axes) instead of RotationSensor.

here how I calculate the inclination of the picture:

```js
function calculateVerticalAngle(or,xr,yr){ //or-orientation xr-xRotation yr-yRotation
    var verticalAngle;
    verticalAngle = xr
    if ( or === 0) {
        verticalAngle=0
    }
    if ( or === 1) {
        //"The Top edge of the device was pointing up. (estimated)"
        verticalAngle-=90
    }
    if ( or === 2) {
        //"The Top edge of the device was pointing down. (estimated)"
        verticalAngle = -90-verticalAngle
    }
    if ( or === 3) {
        //"The Left edge of the device was pointing up. (estimated)"
        if(xr<90 && xr > -90) verticalAngle = yr-90
        else verticalAngle = 90-yr
    }
    if ( or === 4) {
        //"The Right edge of the device was pointing up. (estimated)"
        if(xr<90 && xr >-90) verticalAngle = -yr-90
        else verticalAngle = 90+yr
    }
    if ( or === 5) {
        //"The Face of the device was pointing up. (estimated)"
        verticalAngle =0
    }
    if ( or === 6) {
        //"The Face of the device was pointing down. (estimated)"
        verticalAngle =0
    }
    return verticalAngle
}
```

vertical angle zero is for perfectly vertically hold, minus values are if the phone is inclined down and plus angles for upwards.

if the phone is rotated, then inclination is calculated from y-axes.

Hopefully, I wrote it in an understandable way